# Writing Python list data into CSV file in multiple columns?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to write data into csv file from python list.
I am using aws lambda for this......

My code

```
fields = ['SnapshotId', 'StartDate'] 
csvio = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(csvio,delimiter=',')
writer.writerow(fields)
for x in all_snapshots:
    for snapshot in x['Snapshots']:
        snap_list=[snapshot['SnapshotId'], snapshot['StartTime'].strftime("%b %d %Y")]
        writer.writerows([snap_list])
        print(', '.join(snap_list))
s3.put_object(Body=csvio.getvalue(), ContentType='application/vnd.ms-excel', Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
```

This code is pushing csv file to s3 but all the list values are coming into single csv column with comma seperation. I want to put this into multiple columns.

THis is the csv file generated:

SnapshotId,StartDate

snap-aaaaaaaa,May 25 2016

snap-aaaaaaaaa,Jul 14 2016

This is into single column, but I want seperate columns for snappshot id and start date.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Also for me csv is short for Comma Separated Value and is just a text file where the value (column) are separated by comma so what you get seem right (your problem may be in the display or import of the created csv)

Comment: Issue is in the put object body ?